# How to Get Product Category IDs Without Loading the Whole Product

Tags: product, category, attributes, model, magento-1

By default, you can load product category IDs using this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$category_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

But how can we load the category IDs without loading the whole product model? Note that `getCategoryIds()` is a function of product model not data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setId($_productId);
$categoryIds = $product->getResource()->getCategoryIds($product);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just mentioning it here since this would be possible too (because `getCategoryIds` actually does need the product's Id (pulls it from `$product->getId()`) from the whole submitted model only):

```
$obj = new Varien_Object();
$cats = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getCategoryIds($obj->setId($productId));
```

For the record, that's the `getCategoryIds` method from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`:

```
    /**
     * Retrieve product category identifiers
     *
     * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCategoryIds($product)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();

        $select = $adapter->select()
            ->from($this->_productCategoryTable, 'category_id')
            ->where('product_id = ?', (int)$product->getId());

        return $adapter->fetchCol($select);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

relation between product and category manage it in `catalog_category_product`

you can use this sql query

```
select cc.* from catalog_category_entity cc
   join catalog_category_product cp on cc.entity_id = cp.category_id
   where cp.product_id = {{your product id}};
```

see [Josep's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591036/magento-products-category)

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to getCategoryIds() logic in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product it's enough to have product ID as stated before in [Christoph Farnleitner](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34469/christoph-farnleitner) answer so it can be as easy as:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setId($productId)->getCategoryIds()
```